# Non-blocking pipe using popen?

Tags: c, linux, pipe, popen

I'd like to open a pipe using [`popen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) and have non-blocking 'read' access to it.

How can I achieve this?

(The examples I found were all blocking/synchronous)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Setup like this:

```
FILE *f = popen("./output", "r");
int d = fileno(f);
fcntl(d, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
```

Now you can read:

```
ssize_t r = read(d, buf, count);
if (r == -1 && errno == EAGAIN)
    no data yet
else if (r > 0)
    received data
else
    pipe closed
```

When you're done, cleanup:

```
pclose(f);
```

Comment: the pipe, being a FILE pointer, is inherently buffered, is there any assurance that by using the file descriptor directly you're not going to miss something that was pulled into the file buffer, or can this be guaranteed as long as you don't call fget/fread/etc first?

Answer (score 7):

`popen()` internally calls `pipe()`, `fork()`, `dup2()` (to point the child process's fds 0/1/2 to the pipes) and `execve()`.  Have you considered using these instead?  In that case, you can set the pipe you read to non-blocking using `fcntl()`.

**update**: Here's an example, just for illustrative purposes:

```
int read_pipe_for_command(const char **argv)
{
   int p[2];

   /* Create the pipe. */
   if (pipe(p))
   {
      return -1;
   }

   /* Set non-blocking on the readable end. */
   if (fcntl(p[0], F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK))
   {
      close(p[0]);
      close(p[1]);
      return -1;
   }

   /* Create child process. */
   switch (fork())
   {
      case -1:
          close(p[0]);
          close(p[1]);
          return -1;
      case 0:
          /* We're the child process, close read end of pipe */
          close(p[0]);
          /* Make stdout into writable end */
          dup2(p[1], 1);
          /* Run program */
          execvp(*argv, argv);
          /* If we got this far there was an error... */
          perror(*argv);
          exit(-1);
      default:
          /* We're the parent process, close write end of pipe */
          close(p[1]);
          return p[0];
   }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be: if (pipe(p) < 0) return -1; ?

Comment: @Aktau I like my version better. The syscall will return 0 on success. The if statement tests for non zero.

Comment: you're right, your version is also completely correct, I was thinking of other syscalls!

Comment: Note the parent and child cases are swapped: kill() returns 0 to the child, not the parent.

Comment: Thanks Luca, you are right.  I approved the edit.  (Just 9 years after my answer!)

Answer (score 2):

Never tried it but I don't see why you couldn't grab the file descriptors with fileno(), use fcntl() to set to non-blocking, and use read()/write().  Worth a try.