# Correct Code - Non-blocking pipe with popen

Tags: c++, pipe, popen

There are tons of questions about non blocking pipes, but there are NO examples of code that can be copy&paste (with little correction) and used.

I got the idea and sources from this thread:
[Non-blocking pipe using popen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735781/non-blocking-pipe-using-popen)

But how to use it? At `while` cycle?  Please, review my changes. Is it really need to use `errno == EAGAIN` &  additional header `#include <cerrno>` ?
Suggest you own better version if need:

```
    FILE *pipe;
    char buff[512];
    if ( !(pipe = popen( command.c_str(), "r")) ) return false;

    int d = fileno(pipe);   
    while ( true )
    {
        ssize_t r = read(d, buff, sizeof(buff));
        if (r == -1 && errno == EAGAIN) // really need errno? 
            continue;
        else if (r > 0)
            ptr_output->append(buff);       
        else
            break;
    }

    pclose(pipe);
```

Comment: The pipe isn't non-blocking, you failed to copy'n'paste the right code.

Comment: @JonathanWakely !!! you are amazing! only you found that its blocking! I does not sleep 24h and trying to solve the problem and lose one sting, and ofcouce its does not help. maybe now my threads will not slow down. thnaks.

Comment: You should not edit the question away like that to support [a follow on questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10984490/2509). It leaves this question looking nonsensical. Reproduce the code in the new question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If the `read` call returns with the error value (`-1`) *and* `errno` is set to `EAGAIN`, that means that no data is available, so you `continue` the loop to try again. If you got rid of the `errno`, errors would be effectively ignored, and your program would probably crash. Imagine if you did remove it: When `read` returned `-1`, but, say, the error was that the pipe was broken (the other end closed it), you would just keep trying to loop and enter an infinite loop. Bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

In my Linux multithreaded application *(Ubuntu 16.04, x86_64, Native POSIX Threads, libc.so.6 version Ubuntu GLIBC 2.23-0ubuntu9)*
this code

```
int fd = fileno(pipe);
fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
while (true)
        {
            ssize_t r = read(fd, buff, sizeof(buff));
            if ((r == -1) && (errno == EAGAIN)) // really need errno?
                continue;
            else
            {
                if (r > 0)
                    result += buff;
                else
                    break;
            }
        }
```

even with `fctnl(...)` causes fail as not only output of command but many another arbitrary values from RAM are often read. I think it is due to **thread unsafety of the code**.

(Example: execute `echo` 3 values, 10, 30, and 40, in parallel by 20 threads, `read` the values and display only the last value. Output: 40 QIh MIh 40 40 30...)

**Another code [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/478960/1566267) works fine** due to `fgets` implementation is **thread-safe**:

```
while (!feof(pipe))
{
    if (fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), pipe) != NULL)
    result += buff;
}
```