# Why does popen2() hang between write and read calls?

Tags: c, popen, samtools

I am trying to integrate use of `samtools` into a C program. This [application](http://samtools.sourceforge.net/) reads data in a binary format called BAM, *e.g.* from `stdin`:

```
$ cat foo.bam | samtools view -h -
...
```

(I realize this is a useless use of `cat`, but I'm just showing how a BAM file's bytes can be piped to `samtools` on the command line. These bytes could come from other upstream processes.)

Within a C program, I would like to write chunks of `unsigned char` bytes to the `samtools` binary, while simultaneously capturing the standard output from `samtools` after it processes these bytes.

Because I cannot use `popen()` to simultaneously write to and read from a process, I looked into using publicly-available implementations of `popen2()`, which appears to be written to support this.

I wrote the following test code, which attempts to `write()` 4 kB chunks bytes of a BAM file located in the same directory to a `samtools` process. It then `read()`s bytes from the output of `samtools` into a line buffer, printed to standard error:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define READ 0
#define WRITE 1

pid_t popen2(const char *command, int *infp, int *outfp)
{
    int p_stdin[2], p_stdout[2];
    pid_t pid;

    if (pipe(p_stdin) != 0 || pipe(p_stdout) != 0)
        return -1;

    pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0)
        return pid;
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        close(p_stdin[WRITE]);
        dup2(p_stdin[READ], READ);
        close(p_stdout[READ]);
        dup2(p_stdout[WRITE], WRITE);

        execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", command, NULL);
        perror("execl");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (infp == NULL)
        close(p_stdin[WRITE]);
    else
        *infp = p_stdin[WRITE];

    if (outfp == NULL)
        close(p_stdout[READ]);
    else
        *outfp = p_stdout[READ];

    return pid;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int infp, outfp;

    /* set up samtools to read from stdin */
    if (popen2("samtools view -h -", &infp, &outfp) <= 0) {
        printf("Unable to exec samtools\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    const char *fn = "foo.bam";
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    fp = fopen(fn, "r");
    if (!fp)
        exit(-1);
    unsigned char buf[4096];
    char line_buf[65536] = {0};
    while(1) {
        size_t n_bytes = fread(buf, sizeof(buf[0]), sizeof(buf), fp);
        fprintf(stderr, "read\t-> %08zu bytes from fp\n", n_bytes);
        write(infp, buf, n_bytes);
        fprintf(stderr, "wrote\t-> %08zu bytes to samtools process\n", n_bytes);
        read(outfp, line_buf, sizeof(line_buf));
        fprintf(stderr, "output\t-> \n%s\n", line_buf);
        memset(line_buf, '\0', sizeof(line_buf));
        if (feof(fp) || ferror(fp)) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

(For a local copy of `foo.bam`, here is a [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31495717/foo.bam) to the binary file I am using for testing. But any BAM file would do for testing purposes.)

To compile:

```
$ cc -Wall test_bam.c -o test_bam
```

The problem is that the procedure hangs after the `write()` call:

```
$ ./test_bam
read    -> 00004096 bytes from fp
wrote   -> 00004096 bytes to samtools process
[bam_header_read] EOF marker is absent. The input is probably truncated.
```

If I `close()` the `infp` variable immediately after the `write()` call, then the loop goes through one more iteration before hanging:

```
...
write(infp, buf, n_bytes);
close(infp); /* <---------- added after the write() call */
fprintf(stderr, "wrote\t-> %08zu bytes to samtools process\n", n_bytes);
...
```

With the `close()` statement:

```
$ ./test_bam
read    -> 00004096 bytes from fp
wrote   -> 00004096 bytes to samtools process
[bam_header_read] EOF marker is absent. The input is probably truncated.
[main_samview] truncated file.
output  -> 
@HD VN:1.0 SO:coordinate
@SQ SN:seq1 LN:5000
@SQ SN:seq2 LN:5000
@CO Example of SAM/BAM file format.

read    -> 00004096 bytes from fp
wrote   -> 00004096 bytes to samtools process
```

With this change, I get some output that I'd otherwise expect to get if I ran `samtools` on the command line, but as mentioned, the procedure hangs once again.

How does one use `popen2()` to write and read data in chunks to internal buffers? If this isn't possible, are there alternatives to `popen2()` that would work better for this task?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to a `pipe`, why not communicate with `samtools` through a `socket`? Checking the `samtools` source, the file `knetfile.c` indicates that `samtools` has socket communications available:

```
#include "knetfile.h"

/* In winsock.h, the type of a socket is SOCKET, which is: "typedef
* u_int SOCKET". An invalid SOCKET is: "(SOCKET)(~0)", or signed
* integer -1. In knetfile.c, I use "int" for socket type
* throughout. This should be improved to avoid confusion.
*
* In Linux/Mac, recv() and read() do almost the same thing. You can see
* in the header file that netread() is simply an alias of read(). In
* Windows, however, they are different and using recv() is mandatory.
*/
```

That may provide a better option than using `pipe2`.

Comment: I think this would require importing samtools headers and libraries into this program. I don't see a way to run this binary on the command-line to put it into some kind of daemon mode that would accept connections via a socket. I would be looking for a way to do this through file streams, so that I can make use of the binary as the dependency.

Comment: Fair enough. I saw the socket availability and thought I would offer that as a solution.

Comment: Sorry if it sounds like I'm ungrateful — I'm really not! I do appreciate all suggestions. I just wanted to clarify the problem I'm trying to solve.

Answer (score -2):

This problem has nothing to do with the particular implementation of `popen2`. Also note that on OS X, `popen` lets you open a bidirectional pipe, this may be true on other BSD systems too. If this is to be portable, you'd need a configure check for whether `popen` allows bidirectional pipes (or something equivalent to a configure check).

You need to switch the pipes to non-blocking mode, and alternate between `read` and `write` calls in an endless loop. Such loop, in order not to waste the CPU when the `samtools` process is busy, needs to use `select`, `poll` or a similar mechanism that blocks for a file descriptor to become "available" (more data to read, or ready to accept data for writing).

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1735781/1329652) for some inspiration.

Comment: I'm definitely looking for a portable solution. I'm not sure `popen` will work, if the specifications are as described.

Comment: @AlexReynolds The defacto portable solution is to use `popen2` if the platform provides it, or use `popen` if it's bidirectional on a given platform, or use your own `popen2` if none of those work. And then you switch to nonblocking processing and all is good in the universe :) Configure checks are a must, in some incarnation. You can simply characterize all supported platforms and use a static configuration header that detects the platform and activates the correct implementation. That's what a lot of header-only C++ libraries do, and "compile along" C libs like sqlite amalgamation.

Comment: Would you know how to implement a blocking mechanism that would be relevant to my original question, which uses `popen2()`? It's looks like setting a non-blocking flag on the write descriptor helps, but some data are lost. The question you linked to doesn't offer much help here. I appreciate any details.

Comment: @AlexReynolds "Some data are lost" - huh? How? Why? All you need to do is code up what the second paragraph says. It's a couple dozen lines. It's not that the non-blocking flag "helps", it is impossible to do what you intend without using either non-blocking access or multiple threads.